# Python's `email.message.as_string` encodes some parts as base64; unclear why

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, base64, mime

I wish to use Python's `email` module to change the encoding of MIME mail message parts from `quoted-printable` or `base64` to `7bit` or `8bit`. All seems to work out, except that at the end, for some messages, `email.message.as_string` encodes some parts (`text/plain` and `text/html` both encountered) as `base64`. I do not understand why, and what to understand this behavior to avoid it.

The script code:

```
# Read and parse the message from stdin
msg = email.message_from_string(sys.stdin.read())

for part in msg.walk():
  if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
    if part['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] in {'quoted-printable', 'base64'}:
      payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
      del part['Content-Transfer-Encoding']
      part.set_payload(payload)
      email.encoders.encode_7or8bit(part)

# Send the modified message to stdout
print(msg.as_string())
```

(If this matters: I use Python 3.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `as_bytes` instead. So change your print to:

`print(msg.as_bytes().decode(encoding='UTF-8'))`

reason is in policy documentation 
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email.policy.html#module-email.policy

A cte_type value of 8bit only works with BytesGenerator, not Generator, because strings cannot contain binary data. If a Generator is operating under a policy that specifies cte_type=8bit, it will act as if cte_type is 7bit.

And as_string use Generator, but as_bytes use BytesGenerator which you need

Comment: If I try that, I get `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'as_bytes'`.

Comment: @equaeghe: it is new in Python 3.4; since you are using 3.3 that's unfortunate.

Comment: @equaeghe you still be able use BytesGenerator direcly in 3.3. Just use snippet from as_bytes docs (because it is only convenient method around BytesGenerator)
`from io import BytesIO
from email.generator import BytesGenerator
fp = BytesIO()
g = BytesGenerator(fp, mangle_from_=True, maxheaderlen=60)
g.flatten(msg)
text = fp.getvalue()`

Comment: 3.4 is available and installed on my system in parallel to 3.3, so I can use it by calling python3.4 instead of python3.